# Redirect function not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Redirect function not working after in controller

Our Code

```
function deactive_users($id)
{
        $this->user->deactiveUser($id);
        redirect('admin/manageuser', 'refresh');
}
```

We have run this code no any error display & not redirect to any page but show only blank screen

Comment: have you loaded the url helper ?

Comment: Yes, Just like this : $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','validate_fields_helper');

Comment: Have you sent anything to the browser prior to calling redirect? From the user guide: **In order for this function to work it must be used before anything is outputted to the browser since it utilizes server headers.**

Comment: Then just check the URL or try adding forward slash at beginning redirect('/admin/manageuser', 'refresh');

Comment: Same problem : not working

Comment: problem with function $this->user->deactiveUser($id);comment this line and check

Comment: We have try this but same position

Comment: http://php.nxsolprojects.com/listingsuperadmin/admin/deactive_users/14

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1.**

Not sure but your `Base_url` config variable might be incorrectly set. In `config/config.php` if your `base_url` was set using a single quote. Allowing CI3 to guess the protocol, it would default to `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, which would return ::1 if you are working locally. Furthermore, when you set the variable to `'http://localhost/projectname`', using single quotes the exact same problem should pop up as when it was using the auto `SERVER_ADDR`

**Try to switch the base URL from single, to double quotes.**

Something like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/projectname/";
```

**Solution 2.**

If that doesn't work then go to your `config/config.php` file and edit it where

`$config['log_threshold'] = 0; // change this to 4 so it logs all erros in logs folder`

run your application by the browser and check inside your `/logs` folder the `log.php` file, it will contain all the application errors.

**Solution 3.**

If you see an error like ***Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.*** then try using this:

`if(!isset($CI->session)):
    $CI->load->library('session');
endif;`

Comment: Did you try to comment the line written about redirect function?

Comment: No, function deactive_users($id) { $this->user->deactiveUser($id); redirect('admin/manageuser'); }

Comment: Try to comment  $this->user->deactiveUser($id); and see what happens then.

Comment: We have try this but same position

Comment: What is base URL in your config file? Can you please copy paste it here?

Comment: Not URL of page. I asked for base_url from your config.php file in config folder.

Comment: @NxsolTEam Check my updated answer You can check all logs for more help.

Comment: i thik this is error : DEBUG - 2017-05-01 12:42:33 --> Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.

Comment: @NxsolTEam: Check my 3rd solution. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Solution - 3, where put this code. means which file ?

Comment: In your file's constructor.